# Optimal (low-latency) spark settings for small datasets

Tags: apache-spark

I'm aware that spark is designed for large datasets for which it's great. But under certain circumstances I don't need this scalability, e.g. for unit tests or for data exploration on small datasets. Under these conditions spark performs relatively bad compared implementation in pure scala/python/matlab/R etc.

Note that I don't want to drop spark entirely, I want to keep the framework for larger workloads without re-implementing everything.

How can I disable sparks overhead as much as possible on small datasets (say 10-1000s of records)? I'm tried using only 1 partition in `local` mode (setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1` and `spark.default.parallelism=1`)? Even which these settings, simple queries on 100 records take on the order of 1-2 seconds.

Note that I'm not trying to reduce the time for `SparkSession` instantiation, just the execution time given `SparkSession` exists.

Answer (score -2):

operations in spark have same signature as the scala collections.

You could implement something like:

```
val useSpark = false

val rdd: RDD[String]

val list: List[String] = Nil

def mapping: String => Int = s => s.length


if (useSpark) {
  rdd.map(mapping)
} else {
  list.map(mapping)
}
```

I think this code could be abstracted even more.

Comment: Hi @Vladislav, didn't downvote but I guess people try to test (also) ``DataFrames`` functions using its relational algebra, which can't be covered (easily) by scala collections.